# How to check if a terminal is idle from vscode extension API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-api

I am creating a vscode extension which opens a terminal and executes a command. I don't want to create unnecessary terminals but reuse any existing terminal that is sitting idle. Is this possible?

Note: I have tried the vscode `terminal.existStatus` checking which is supposed to be undefined only if terminal is active. But I see that it is always undefined.